# What is the meaning of having a variable="+" ? SAS (sql)

Tags: sql, sas

I'm new to SAS and I'm trying to understand a code:

```
if MAP_ID="+" then output WORK.0201_template;
else
do;
   SHEET_ID=MAP_ID;
   output WORK.0201_template_f;
end;
```

What does it mean the MAP_ID="+"? Does it mean that it search on the table for the values where MAP_ID=+, or does it have another menaing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `MAP_ID="+"` is a boolean expression that compares the value the variable `MAP_ID` to the character string literal `"+"`.  It will be true when they are the same and false otherwise.

I suspect that the main purpose of this code is to split the data into two different output datasets based on the value of `MAP_ID`.

It also is changing the value of `SHEET_ID`.  That type of code also looks like something that is designed to carry forward the value of `MAP_ID` in a retained field `SHEET_ID`. If I am right then the meaning of the value of `+` is to keep the same sheet_id.  But we would need to seem more of the code and the data to really tell.

Comment: so is it true when MAP_ID=+? the MAP_ID value must be +?

Comment: Yes. When MAP_ID is + then the first OUTPUT statement will run. And when it isn't then the else clause runs instead.

Comment: but the problem is that MAP_ID has a fix list of values. And + is not one of the possible values. That's why I'm not understanding.

Comment: If it never has that value then it will always execute the ELSE part of that code.  We can't really help you with understanding why the program was written that way. :)

Comment: @ArleteFerreira  Look at your two template files, how are they different? What would you be using them for that differs? That's where I'd start.